# Converting function to comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I would like to convert the following function into a simplified list comprehension

```
def number_of_consonants(words):
    words_split = words.split()
    consonant_list = [len([letter for letter in word if letter.lower() not in 'aeiou']) \
            for word in words_split]
    return print(consonant_list)
```

The function simply counts the number of consonants for each word in a string

Comment: It's not clear what this is intended to do, nor if it even does that.

Comment: `return print(...)` is definitely pointless...

Answer (score 1):

You can count up the number of consonants more easily by using `sum` with a generator expression, rather than building a list and taking its `len`.  Other than that, all you need to do to make this function shorter is get rid of the intermediate variable declarations and just print the list.  There's no point in `return`ing the `print` since `print()` always returns `None` anyway.

```
def number_of_consonants(words):
    print([
        sum(letter not in 'aeiou' for letter in word.lower())
        for word in words.split()
    ])
```

```
>>> number_of_consonants("the quick brown fox")
[2, 3, 4, 2]
```

If you wanted to `return` the list rather than printing it, just replace `print([...])` with `return [...]`.